# jupyter lab search / find in outputs - shortcut

Tags: python, firefox, find, keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-lab

I'm using Jupyter Lab in Firefox. (on an Ubuntu system)

If I'm using ctrl + f in a Jupyter lab tab, then a box opens in the upper right part of the tab. There I may enter what I would like to find.

But if I have e.g. the calculation 37*3 in the cell and 111 as a result in the output

```
37*3
> 111
```

I can find the 37 with the mentioned search but not the 111.

I still may use the standard Firefox search which searches in the output as well. But since the shortcut ctrl+f is now used for the Jupyter Lab internal search, I can't open it with a keyboard-shortcut anymore. (In the menu bar I have to click on "edit" "find in page" which takes more time.)

Does anyone have a faster solution for this? (Ideally without changing the shortcuts / or at least without changing the firefox-shortcut ctrl+f)

Answer (score 0):

In my JupyterLab, version 3.1.17, I can search in output using JupyterLab's internal search with Firefox and Chrome.

If someone is still struggling with this, it is possible to use browser's search Ctrl + F shortcut after clicking on the top bar (or the left bar), which is faster than reaching the option inside the menu.